# Error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." while taking backup of SQL Files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to take backup of a few user databases on SQL Server 2008 R2. 
I am running the following script on Powershell v2.0.

```
#load SQL snap-in
Add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-pssnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

#pull the current date
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyddMM

#set location of backup files
$directory = "F:\sql\backup"

#Grab the database names
$dbname = dir 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyServer\DEFAULT\Databases\MyDataBase' | Select Name

#Backup each user database found.
$dbname | foreach { $_.Name.ToString() } | foreach {$bakfile = "$directory" + $_ + "_" + $date + ".bak";
"Backing up Database: $_"; Invoke-Sqlcmd -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query 
"BACKUP DATABASE $_ TO DISK=N'$bakfile' WITH INIT";
   }
```

But this script shows me the following error in succession:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\sql\backup.ps1:40 char:21
+ $dbname | foreach { $_.Name.ToString() } | foreach {$bakfile = "$directory" + $_ ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

- What exactly is this error?
- Where is it occurring?
- How to correct this?
- what changes should I make if I want to save the backup
  file in '.sql' form?
- Is there any other simpler way?

Comment: Remove the `\MyDataBase` part. There is no Name property when you're inside the database context.

Comment: at the `..\MyDataBase` level the `get-childitem` cmdlet retuns the name's list of the tables present in `mydatabases` database.